# C# Razor getting null for radio button

Tags: c#, razor, radio-button

I'm getting a `null` value on submit server side for my radio button. All other properties of the model are OK.

Here's part of the view with the radiobutton:

```
Traitement @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => Model.SearchQuery.TypeService,  "Traitement",new { @id="rbTraitement"})
Catégorisation @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => Model.SearchQuery.TypeService, "Catégorisation", new { @id = "rbCat" })
```

In my model, this is the property:

```
[Display(Name = "Service responsable du traitement ou de la catégorisation", Prompt = "Service responsable du traitement ou de la catégorisation")]
public string TypeService { get; set; }
```

In the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SearchTraitement(SearchQueryModel query)
{
  var searchResult = CurrentPlainteBO.SearchPlaintes(query);
  return PartialView("_resultsTraitement", searchResult);
}
```

Comment: The method in the controller is actually this:     [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SearchTraitement(SearchQueryModel query)
        {
            var searchResult = CurrentPlainteBO.SearchPlaintes(query);
            return PartialView("_resultsTraitement", searchResult);
        }

Comment: Can you post the @model expression in your view? Also, is SearchQuery a property of SearchQueryModel?

Answer (score 0):

The following simplified code works:

**View:**

```
@model c_sharp_razor_getting_null.Models.SearchQueryModel

@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutPage.cshtml";
}

@{Html.BeginForm();}
Traitement @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => Model.TypeService, "Traitement", new { @id = "rbTraitement" })
Catégorisation @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => Model.TypeService, "Catégorisation", new { @id = "rbCat" })
<input type="submit" name="OKButton" value="OK" />
@{Html.EndForm();}
```

**Controller:**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index() {
        SearchQueryModel searchQuery = new SearchQueryModel() { TypeService = "Catégorisation" };
        return View(searchQuery);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(SearchQueryModel query)
    {
        return View(query);
    }
}
```

**Model:**

```
public class SearchQueryModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Service responsable du traitement ou de la catégorisation", Prompt = "Service responsable du traitement ou de la catégorisation")]
    public string TypeService { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended by writing regular HTML. Nothing was working:

```
  Traitement<input type="radio" name="TypeService" value="Traitement" checked="checked">
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Catégorisation<input type="radio" name="TypeService" value="Catégorisation">
```